# How to use multiple tables for one row of one table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

So for the project I'm working on, I have three different tables, each holding values for individual objects. Another table is used to hold all the chosen values (not all of them!) from the three tables. I don't want a new column for every different table (as shown in the picture below), I want a row that would specify which table to use so it can use it. So basically the main table holds some of the same values from the other three tables.

I made a mock example to help explain the question. I know its kind of lame but I hope you get an idea about whats going on.

[image]

If this isn't possible using MySQL, please let me know any better suggestions. Thank you

Comment: It sound to me like `left join` but I can't be sure. provide sample data and expected result to understand it better.

Comment: Avoid natural keys like `Breed`, `Species`, and `Type`. They are very susceptible of changing in the future. It's better to create an `id` column as PK; your columns will become just normal attributes of each table.

Comment: by viewing the mock i didn't see any reference ID from 3 tables in animal table. secondly if you provide reference ID. you will not need to same values in animal table. or please provide some more details why is that?

Answer (score 0):

According to the pics,those tables got nothing to indicate where to bind them.This will cause the Animal table become a totally chaos with `JOIN`. BUT if you just want to have a long list of all the row from specific column (which I think OP actually want) use`UNION`

```
Select Breed from Cats
UNION ALL
Select Species from Reptiles
UNION ALL
Select Type from Birds
```

this should get the list might be what you want.

Comment: I guess union will get double values, as you can see there is same values in all tables.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for. I'll edit my post and show an example